# Getting multiple items from a FilterStore [Python][Simpy]

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I am using Python and [Simpy](http://simpy.readthedocs.io/) for a simulation. In the simulation jobs are processed by resources. Some jobs require a single resource, other jobs require multiple resources. I would like to retrieve (get) multiple resources at once therefore prioritizing jobs which need fewer resources.

The resources are represented by items in a [FilterStore](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/api_reference/simpy.resources.store.html#simpy.resources.store.FilterStore).

The example solution below makes use of a for loop and reserves resources. I am looking for a solution which doesn't reserve resources, but assigned resources to jobs for which all resources are available. The example below is simplified, but I am looking for a solution which allows me to yield a large number of resources at the same time, similar to the [AllOf event](http://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topical_guides/events.html?highlight=allof).

I came across a [suggestion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/python-simpy/putting$20getting%7Csort:relevance/python-simpy/kb3JtarXwpM/df7kGukeBAAJ) to create a subclass of the FilterStore object, but I don't know how to go about this. I also came across an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38150988/simpy-store-batch-processing) in which a subclass for the store object is used. Is there a way to achieve the intended behavior without creating a subclass? If not, how can a subclass for the FilterStore be created?

Code:

```
import simpy

def source(env, jobs):
    count = 0
    for i in jobs:
        env.process(job(env, count, i))
        count += 1
        yield env.timeout(1)

def job(env, count, resources_required):
    resources_used = []
    # the for loop yield (reserves) resources even if not all    resources are available
    print('job: {} requires resources: {} at time: {}'.format(count,  resources_required, env.now))
    for i in resources_required:
        resource = yield resources.get(lambda resource: resource['id'] == i)
        resources_used.append(resource)
    print('job: {} retrieved resources: {} at time: {}'.format(count, resources_required, env.now))
    yield env.timeout(4)
    for i in resources_used:
        yield resources.put(i)
    print('job: {} released resources: {} completed at time: {}'.format(count, resources_required, env.now))

env = simpy.Environment()
resources = simpy.FilterStore(env, capacity=3)
for i in range(resources.capacity):
    resources.put({'id': i})

jobs = [
    [2],
    [0],
    [2, 0],
    [2],
    [2, 0]
]

env.process(source(env, jobs))
env.run(until=50)
```

Output:

```
job: 0 requires resources: [2] at time: 0
job: 0 retrieved resources: [2] at time: 0
job: 1 requires resources: [0] at time: 1
job: 1 retrieved resources: [0] at time: 1
job: 2 requires resources: [2, 0] at time: 2
job: 3 requires resources: [2] at time: 3
job: 4 requires resources: [2, 0] at time: 4
job: 0 released resources: [2] completed at time: 4
job: 1 released resources: [0] completed at time: 5
job: 2 retrieved resources: [2, 0] at time: 5
job: 3 retrieved resources: [2] at time: 9
job: 2 released resources: [2, 0] completed at time: 9
job: 3 released resources: [2] completed at time: 13
job: 4 retrieved resources: [2, 0] at time: 13
job: 4 released resources: [2, 0] completed at time: 17
```

In the example that means that job 3 should be prioritized over job 2. At time 4 all resources required for job 3 are available. However, job 2 reserved one of the resources (2) at time 2 and is started before job 3.

Sequence of jobs:

```
current sequence: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
desired sequence: [0, 1, 3, 2, 4]
```

Update:

The code below takes a slightly different approach. It avoid the FilterStore. Rather, it makes use of multiple Stores enclosed together with an id in a dictionary. The id makes it possible to find the correct resources in two of the stores. To withdraw two resources from two different stores at the time time, I made use of the following statement: 'yield env.all_of'. Still, the sequence is not as desired. Resources seem to get reserved.

```
Code:

import simpy
import random
import collections

def source(env, jobs):
    count = 0
    for i in jobs:
        env.process(job(env, count, i))
        count += 1
        yield env.timeout(1)

def job(env, count, resources_required):
    resources_used = []
    #resources_required = random.sample(range(0, 5), random.randint(1, 5))
    # the for loop yield (reserves) resources even if not all resources are available
    print('job: {} requires resources: {} at time: {}'.format(count, resources_required, env.now))
    resources_needed = []
    for i in resources_required:
        for j in resources:
            if i == j['id']:
                resources_needed.append(j['store'].get())
    yield env.all_of(resources_needed)
    print('job: {} retrieved resources: {} at time: {}'.format(count, resources_required, env.now))
    yield env.timeout(4)
    for i in resources_needed:
        i.resource.put(i)
    print('job: {} released resources: {} completed at time: {}'.format(count, resources_required, env.now))
    sequence.append(count)

env = simpy.Environment()
resources = []
capacity = 1
for i in range(5):
    resource = collections.OrderedDict()
    store = simpy.Store(env, capacity=capacity)
    for j in range(capacity):
        item = {'resource_id': i,
                'item_id': j
                }
        store.put(item)
    resource = {'id': i,
                'store': store
    }

    resources.append(resource)

jobs = [
    [2],
    [0],
    [2, 0],
    [2],
    [2, 0]
]

sequence = []
random.seed(1234567890)
env.process(source(env, jobs))
env.run(until=50)
print('...')
print('current sequence: {}'.format(sequence))
print('desired sequence: [0, 1, 3, 2, 4]')
```

Outcome:

```
job: 0 requires resources: [2] at time: 0
job: 0 retrieved resources: [2] at time: 0
job: 1 requires resources: [0] at time: 1
job: 1 retrieved resources: [0] at time: 1
job: 2 requires resources: [2, 0] at time: 2
job: 3 requires resources: [2] at time: 3
job: 0 released resources: [2] completed at time: 4
job: 4 requires resources: [2, 0] at time: 4
job: 1 released resources: [0] completed at time: 5
job: 2 retrieved resources: [2, 0] at time: 5
job: 2 released resources: [2, 0] completed at time: 9
job: 3 retrieved resources: [2] at time: 9
job: 3 released resources: [2] completed at time: 13
job: 4 retrieved resources: [2, 0] at time: 13
job: 4 released resources: [2, 0] completed at time: 17
```

Sequence of jobs:

```
current sequence: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
desired sequence: [0, 1, 3, 2, 4]
```

Update 2:

The code below again takes a slightly different approach. Now, instead of a store a PriorityResource is used. The resource is again wrapped in a dictionary object. By prioritizing the jobs which require less resources, the desired sequence can be obtained (with the list of jobs above). However, now shorter jobs are always prioritized, which wasn't my intend. Jobs for which all resources are available should be prioritized over jobs for which some resources are available. I've changed the lists of jobs below to reflect the problem. The problem could potentially be solved if it was possible to prioritize jobs based on the time in the 'future' when all resources for a job will be available. Is it possible to determine when there resources become available?

Code:

```
import simpy
import random

def source(env, jobs):
    count = 0
    for i in jobs:
        env.process(job(env, count, i))
        yield env.timeout(1)
        count += 1

def job(env, count, resources_required):
    print('job: {} requires resources: {} at time: {}'.format(count, resources_required, env.now))
    resources_needed = []
    for i in resources_required:
        for j in resources:
            if i == j['id']:
                resources_needed.append(j['resource'].request(priority=len(resources_required)))
    yield env.all_of(resources_needed)
    print('job: {} retrieved resources: {} at time: {}'.format(count, resources_required, env.now))
    yield env.timeout(4)
    for i in resources_needed:
        i.resource.release(i)
    print('job: {} released resources: {} completed at time: {}'.format(count, resources_required, env.now))
    sequence.append(count)

env = simpy.Environment()

resources = []
capacity = 1
for i in range(5):
    resource = {
        'id': i,
        'resource': simpy.PriorityResource(env, capacity=capacity)
    }
    resources.append(resource)

jobs = [
    [2, 0],
    [1],
    [2, 0],
    [2],
    [2, 0]
]

sequence = []
random.seed(1234567890)
env.process(source(env, jobs))
env.run(until=50)
print('...')
print('current sequence: {}'.format(sequence))
print('desired sequence: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]')
```

Output:

```
job: 0 requires resources: [2, 0] at time: 0
job: 0 retrieved resources: [2, 0] at time: 0
job: 1 requires resources: [1] at time: 1
job: 1 retrieved resources: [1] at time: 1
job: 2 requires resources: [2, 0] at time: 2
job: 3 requires resources: [2] at time: 3
job: 0 released resources: [2, 0] completed at time: 4
job: 4 requires resources: [2, 0] at time: 4
job: 3 retrieved resources: [2] at time: 4
job: 1 released resources: [1] completed at time: 5
job: 3 released resources: [2] completed at time: 8
job: 2 retrieved resources: [2, 0] at time: 8
job: 2 released resources: [2, 0] completed at time: 12
job: 4 retrieved resources: [2, 0] at time: 12
job: 4 released resources: [2, 0] completed at time: 16
```

Sequence of jobs:

```
current sequence: [0, 1, 3, 2, 4]
desired sequence: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Are you implementing backfilling with priorities? Since having enough resources, if you set a higher priority to a job that requests 1 resource than another that requests 2 resources but it was submitted first, it would not be fair.